# libc++ / libstdc++ : Same regex, different results

Tags: c++, regex, compatibility, libstdc++, libc++

I've got the follwing code, which prints '6' when using libstdc++ and '7' when using libc++ (which is the length of a regex match).

In my opinion the libstdc++ behaviour is correct but I am not sure.

More importantly: what can I do to ensure the same behaviour on both libraries ?

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::regex reg{R"_(\{(-?[0-9]+)\.\.(-?[0-9]+)})_"};
    std::string str = "{-2..2}";

    std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rit (str.begin(), str.end(), reg);
    std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend;

    std::cout << rit->length();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `}` be `\}`?

Comment: well spotted, thanks! this solves my "concrete" problem, but I'd still like to have the same behaviour every time for a given input regex.

Comment: If you need a consistent behavior, use one and the same library, like Boost. There are a lot of questions devoted to discrepancies between C++ regex libraries, and the usual remedy is just sticking to Boost.

Comment: You can report a bug against either libstdc++ (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) or libc++ (https://bugs.llvm.org) once you decide what the correct answer should be.